# why does multiprocessing create a clone for base variables for each thread

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

So I'm using multiprocessing pool with 3 threads, to run a function that does a certain job, and I have a variable defined outside this function which equals 0, and every time the function do it job it should add 1 to that variable and print it, but every thread uses a separated variable

here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

number_of_doe_jobs = 0

def thefunction():
 global number_of_doe_jobs
 # JOB CODE GOES HERE
 number_of_doe_jobs+=1

if __name__ =="__main__":
    p = Pool(3)
    p.map(checker, datalist)
```

the desired output is that it adds 1 to number_of_doe_jobs ,
but every thread add 1 to it own number_of_doe_jobs , so there are 3 number_of_doe_jobs variables now.

Answer (score 1):

You are not spawning 3 threads.  You are spawning 3 processes.  Each process has its own memory space, with its own copy of the interpreter and its own independent object space.   Global variables are not shared across processes.  There are ways to create shared variables (which communicate over sockets), but you might be better served by using a `multiprocessing.Queue`.  Create it in the mainline code, and pass it as a parameter to the subprocesses.  Have the jobs push a "complete" flag on the queue, and have the mainline code read the results.

### FOLLOWUP

The NUMBER of jobs will always be equal to `len(datalist)`, so it's not clear why you would track that.  Here, I create a multiprocessing queue and pass that to the function.  Python implements that by creating a socket.  The checker function sends a signal when it finishes, and the mainline code fetches each one and prints it.  `q.get` will block until something is in the queue.

```
import multiprocessing

def checker(q):
    # JOB CODE GOES HERE
    q.put( "done" )

if __name__ =="__main__":
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = Pool(3)
    p.map(lambda: checker(q), datalist)

    for _ in datalist:
        print( q.get() )
```

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, may you please demonstrate that in a code?